# Can't edit ListBox-Foreground

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, listbox

first off all: Sorry for the bad english, I usually speak german.

Currently I am working on a big project where I have to fill a listbox, which I use as "navigation-control", with strings from a dictionary.

In an older version of this project i put the strings in the listbox manually, and then i could set the foreground of the listbox from black to white, but in the current version it is not possible anymore.

```
   <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Vertical">
        <TextBlock Text=" Navigation" FontSize="16" Margin="10" Foreground="White"/>

        <ListBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" 
            VerticalAlignment="Stretch" 
            HorizontalContentAlignment="Left"
            Margin="10"
            MaxHeight="150"
            BorderBrush="Black"
            Style="{DynamicResource MetroListBox}"
            SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTemplate}" Background="#002B2B2B" 
            ItemsSource="{x:Static models:TemplateRepository.TemplateDictionary}" 
            Foreground="White"
            DisplayMemberPath="Value">
        </ListBox>
    </StackPanel>
```

Can anyone explain to me why this not works?

Comment: What is specified in the sytle `MetroListBox`? It may be overriding

Comment: @Hank, local value has [precedence](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230(v=vs.110).aspx) over style setters, but perhaps the style redefines `ItemTemplate` (`ListBoxItem`) and/or panel style, therefore setting `Foreground` doesn't have effect on anything anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is difficult to guess without some more information like what is the template for items of `ListBox`?
For example you could have following template in Resources:

```
<DataTemplate  DataType="{x:Type local:SomeClass}">
    <Grid DataContext="{Binding}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Foreground="{Binding Foreground, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}" />
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
```

In such case setting `Foreground` to some value would affect items, e.g:

```
<ListBox x:Name="listBox" ItemsSource="{Binding}"  Foreground="Red">
```

On the other hand if `Foreground` of Items is set to some fixed value  in datatemplate then  setting it also in ListBox will have no effect.